# Displaying duplicates in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, duplicates

I would like to display the duplicates of a dataframe in order to get a better understanding. I would like to groupby the duplicated rows

This example hopefully clarifies what I want to do. Assume we have given the dataframe below

```
CC BF FA WC Strength
1  2  3  4   1
2  3  4  5   6
1  2  3  4   8
1  2  3  4   4
2  3  4  5   7
```

Here rows 1,3,4 and 2,5 are duplicates after removing Strength. I would like to get a new dataframe that displays

```
CC BF FA WC Strength_min Strength_max Count
1  2  3  4  1            8             3
2  3  4  5  6            7             2
```

Comment: How about using `duplicated` function from pandas? https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html

Comment: I tried ``` df['CC','BF', "FA", "WC"].duplicated()]``` which returns a dataframe containing all the duplicates, which in this case would be the original dataframe. right?

Comment: mozway already provided working solution, so let's leave the `duplicated` method :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a custom [`groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html) with the output from [`Index.difference`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.difference.html) as grouper:

```
(df.groupby(list(df.columns.difference(['Strength'], sort=False)))['Strength']
   .agg(**{'Strength_min': 'min', 'Strength_max': 'max', 'Count': 'count'})
   .reset_index()
)
```

Output:

```
   CC  BF  FA  WC  Strength_min  Strength_max  Count
0   1   2   3   4             1             8      3
1   2   3   4   5             6             7      2
```

Comment: This is definitely a nice approach. OP might be wondering why change of column order?. To clarify that, `df.columns.difference` returns column names in alphabetical order.

Comment: @JamiuS. yes, that's right, you can pass `sort=False` to avoid this (see update)